# Is the set $\{ (x,\sin(\frac{1}{x}) ) | x \in (0,1)\}$ a manifold with and without the origin

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Is the set $A = \{ (x,\sin(\frac{1}{x}) ) | x \in (0,1)\}$ a manifold with and without the origin.

So without the origin $(0,0)$ I'm pretty sure that it is a manifold, since in each point the set is a graph of a smooth function. we can also present $A$ with the implicit function $F(x,y) = y - sin(\frac{1}{x})$.

However, with the origin I am pretty sure that $A$ is not a manifold, but I don't know how to prove it formally. The way I know to prove a set is not a manifold, is to show that at any open environment of the origin $(0,0)$, $A$ is not a graph of a function. I haven't learned anything about manifolds and connectedness.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean Differentiable Manifold  by manifold?

Comment: A smooth manifold. There 4 different definitions that are equal

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a manifold then any neighborhood of $(0,0)$ is homeomorphic of open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. But open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are path connected while every neighborhood of $(0,0)$ in $A$ are not path-connected. Hence $A$ can not be manifold if $(0,0)$  is included because path-connectedness property is preserved by homeomorphism.

Comment: Is there a way to show this without using path connectivity?

Comment: @GabiG,  It perhaps has.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can show that in every neighborhood of $(0,0)$ the set $M$ is not a graph of a function. Since if $x = f(y)$ then we have two values of $x$ for the same value of $y$, and if $y = f(x)$ then i every neighborhood of $x=0$ the function is not smooth. I think this proves it.

Comment: @GabiG, $M$ or $A$ ?

Comment: $A$, my mistake